# Creating a table and populating with a merge

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL 2008 R2 table that consists of (col1(char), col2(int, prim key), col3(char)).

I am populating the table with...

```
MERGE [dbo].[Data] as target
USING 
(
SELECT 01, 1, 'Data1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 03, 2, 'Data2'
UNION ALL 
SELECT D2, 3, 'Data3'
)AS source ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3])
ON (target.[Col2] = source.[Col2])
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET [Col1] = source.[Col1],
               [col3] = source.[col3]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
    INSERT ([col1], [col2], [col3])
    VALUES (source.[col1],source.[col2], source.[col3]);
```

It populates fine, aside from the "SELECT D2, 3, 'Data3'" statement, and throws an invalid column name. Any ideas why or how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this little char to col1: `'`

```
MERGE [dbo].[Data] as target
USING 
(
SELECT '01' Col1, 1 Col2, 'Data1' Col3
UNION ALL 
SELECT '03', 2, 'Data2'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'D2', 3, 'Data3'
)AS source ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3])
ON (target.[Col2] = source.[Col2])
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET [Col1] = source.[Col1],
               [col3] = source.[col3]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
    INSERT ([col1], [col2], [col3])
    VALUES (source.[col1],source.[col2], source.[col3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need D2 in quotes, like this: 'D2', if its a string. If it's a column from a table, you need to do `SELECT D2, 3, 'Data3' FROM <table>`